# blazor wasm PWA not loading offline after installed as desktop app

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, progressive-web-apps, blazor-webassembly, offlineapps

I am trying to make a Blazor WASM PWA load offline after being installed as a desktop app but not sure what I am missing.

I checked on the publish the generated service-worker-assets.js and service-worker.js and seems to be correct.

here are the errors:

**Failed to load resource: net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED /_framework/blazor.boot.json:1**

**TypeError: Failed to fetch
(anonymous) @ blazor.webassembly.js:1**

What can I be missing?

Comment: Is this a blazor hosted template as well as PWA? If so, then the Azure DevOps pipeline may default to publishing from the client project instead of the server project, which will prevent certain resources from loading into the browser. So if it's a hosted app, then you might check the yml file (or just publish from the Server proj in VS, and see if that resolves the issue)

Answer (score 1):

Is this happening in a published Project? If you are installing it via Debug/Release Mode in VS then the problem is that it uses `self.addEventListener('fetch', () => { });` which does not actually install the resources needed to run offline.

Comment: thank you Black-Pawn-C7 I am using Azure DevOps pipelines to publish using a build in release mode. If I go and check the content of the published service-worker.js is the same as service-worker.published.js I have in my VS project. Is there any extra step I am missing?

Comment: publishing the app to IIS and then installing it (from chrome) worked for me.

Comment: it works offline on the PC but still does not work offline on the mobile